# Synchronise Python distribution across multiple Macs

Tags: python, macos, synchronization, dropbox

Does anyone know if there is a way to keep the Python libraries on both of my macs synchronised? I am just getting into Python, and really enjoying using it!

I have two macs, and I keep my Python documents in Dropbox, so that they are accessible from both computers. However, whenever I install a new module, I have to do it manually on both computers. If I could keep them synchronised I would be very happy! :)

Comment: If you use virtual environments and `requirements.txt` files for your projects, rather than having one long list of modules for everything, this would become much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no specific way for an individual to do that just with the Mac itself; something like [Casper](http://www.jamfsoftware.com/products/casper-suite/) could be used but it's like shooting off a cannon to kill a gnat in this case.

I'd go one step further than @jonrsharpe's recommendation of virtualenv, and say that what you really need is [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) or [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com). Any project I do (even ones for home), I use Vagrant to keep things in order. Vagrant has a cloud service called [Atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/) for keeping things in sync, but I've never really used it, since I don't actively switch back and forth between machines. I just keep the provisioning scripts up-to-date in git, and then I can fire up a dev environment on any machine at any time.

For a very involved project, I'd suggest maintaining your environment with something like [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/intro.html), but a simple bash script to provision your dev environment by installing some APT packages and a requirements.txt for pip packages should keep everything straight.

Comment: Thanks! Docker looks like exactly what I need. I will try it out this week! 

I really appreciate the help – am teaching myself Python, having never taken a computing course, and nearly every question that I have has already been tackled somewhere. What a great community. :)